# Are keyframes in local or world space?

Tags: transforms, keyframes, coordinates

When I insert a keyframe (locrot for example), are the coordinates in local or in world space?

For example:
when I animate a character through its armature. I define an action for moving a hand, by inserting a keyframe on the whole character. Then I have the translation action, built on whole character keyframe.

What I cant understand is:
if the keyframe I inserted for the hand is in world space, then the hand should stay at the position where I inserted the keyframe. And when the character will translate, there should be a problem with the hand animated, indeed the body will translate but the hand would stay in place.

Comment: I think keyframes record global space, since they record object (eg locrot) changes. The hand is not an object, is a part of the armature object. ?